# Is a matrix a subgroup of a group when its the inverse matrix "looks different"?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I have the to prove whether a subset of a group is a subgroup. The following subset is given:

$$U = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in GL(3,\mathbb{R}) \ \bigg | a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \subset (GL(3,\mathbb{R}), \cdot)$$

One of the criteria is $\forall x \in U : x^{-1} \in U$. So I calculated the inverse matrix and got:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{a} & -\frac{b}{a} & \frac{cb}{da} \\ 0 & 1 & -\frac{c}{d} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{d} \end{pmatrix}$$

My question now is: The matrix given in the group has the value 0 on $a_{13}$. The inverse matrix does not fulfill this criteria for all $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, since its value is $\frac{cb}{da}$. Does this mean that U is not a subgroup of $(GL(3,\mathbb{R}),\cdot)$? I am asking this because I first thought that the only thing I have to prove is that the entries inside the matrix are still $\in \mathbb{R}$ but this somehow does not make sense...

Thank you very much for your help!
FunkyPeanut

Comment: The answer to your main question is “yes, this means $U$ is not a subgroup.” To be a subgroup you need to check it is (1) a subset (that the real entries part, along with $ad \neq 0$), (2) closed under multiplication, and (3) closed under inverses. If it fails any of those three, then it is not a subgroup. $U$ passes (1) and fails (2) and (3), though you only described the check for (3).

Comment: Thanks that was all I wanted to know :)